# get hierarchical data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display menu from mysql database. This is what I tried so far and don't know what is the error for.
I appreciate any help . I posted the table that I want to display and the error that I got

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\wamp\www\second _try\eCRA.php on line 18

```
<?php
    function display_menu($parent, $level) {
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT n.id, n.menu_name, n.link, d.count FROM 'menu' n 
        LEFT OUTER  JOIN(SELECT parent, COUNT (*) AS count FROM 'menu' GROUP BY
        parent) d ON  n.id=d.parent  W HERE n.parent=".$parent);
        echo"<ul>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            if($row['count']>0) {
                echo"<li><a href='" .$row['link']. "'>". $row['menu_name'] ."</a>";
                display_menu($row['id'], $level + 1);
                echo"</li>";
            }//f
            elseif($row['count']==0) { 
                echo"<li><a href='". $row['link'] ."'>". $row['menu_name'] ."</a></li>";
            }else; 
        }//w
        echo"</ul>";
    }

    display_menu(0,2);
?>
```

`![error][1]`
`![Table][2]`

Comment: Your query fails, therefore `$query` is initialized with `false`. Use `mysql_error()` to investigate your issue.

Comment: Your mysql_query call is returning `false` due to an error. (You should check for this before using `$query`). Assuming the space in `W HERE` is a typo in your question then you need to use `mysql_error` to show the database error. i.e `echo mysql_error();` just after the `mysql_query` call.

Comment: A little reminder: Standard mysql library is currently marked as deprecated and all code depending on it should be rewritten with mysqli classes. Furthermore, error handling should never be omitted from project code. In your case, you should always check value of `$query` before your main logic.

Comment: Just FYI, by convention, where you use $query, I would use $result... and "W HERE" looks a bit odd

Comment: @SpaceDog i got this ////You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) AS count FROM `menu` GROUP BY parent) d ON n.id=d.parent WHERE n.parent=0' at line 1

Comment: The other answers below point out the error (the quotes round the table name). But the best way to debug this is to print the query string after you create it, then test it on the command line of mysql (or in a web interface like phpMyAdmin). Once you have the working SQL you can go back and fix the code that generates it.

Answer (score 0):

On line `11` you have `$row['count']` which means you are retrieving the column `count` which is not in in your database columns (As per your attached image), I think you want this.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
//do stuff here 
}
elseif(mysql_num_rows($query)>==0){
//do stuff here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's wrong:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT n.id, n.menu_name, n.link, d.count FROM 'menu' n 
    LEFT OUTER  JOIN(SELECT parent, COUNT (*) AS count FROM 'menu' GROUP BY
    parent) d ON  n.id=d.parent  W HERE n.parent=".$parent);
```

You're using single quotes for referencing to a table name. You cannot do that. You'd need to use **backticks** for that!

Like so:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT n.id, n.menu_name, n.link, d.count FROM `menu` n 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent, COUNT (*) AS count FROM `menu` GROUP BY
    parent) d ON  n.id=d.parent  W HERE n.parent=".$parent);
```

I would also like to point out that your code is possibly vulnerable to SQL injection.
Look into that, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong syntax. `FROM 'menu'` should be with backticks instead of single quotes:

```
  FROM `menu`
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query fails to get the result use **mysql_error()**  to find the problem

```
 function display_menu($parent, $level) {
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT n.id, n.menu_name, n.link, d.count FROM 'menu' n 
    LEFT OUTER  JOIN(SELECT parent, COUNT (*) AS count FROM 'menu' GROUP BY
    parent) d ON  n.id=d.parent  W HERE n.parent=".$parent) or die(mysql_error());
    echo"<ul>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        if($row['count']>0) {
            echo"<li><a href='" .$row['link']. "'>". $row['menu_name'] ."</a>";
            display_menu($row['id'], $level + 1);
            echo"</li>";
        }//f
        elseif($row['count']==0) { 
            echo"<li><a href='". $row['link'] ."'>". $row['menu_name'] ."</a></li>";
        }else; 
    }//w
    echo"</ul>";
}

display_menu(0,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming parent is numeric, try this...

```
SELECT n.id
     , n.menu_name
     , n.link
     , d.count 
  FROM menu n 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT parent 
            , COUNT (*) count 
         FROM menu
        GROUP 
           BY parent
     ) d 
    ON n.id = d.parent 
 WHERE n.parent = $parent;
```